# Show validation message for Hidden field

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

May be this can be a question some more similar to others But I haven't find the solution that I want from those.

I want to show the Validation message I have set for particular field in MVC::

My ViewModel is::

```
 public class MainDocumentViewModel
    {


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Valid Customer Name")]
        public long CustomerID { get; set; }
    }
```

My View is as ::

```
<form>

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CustomerID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.CustomerID)

 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But after submitting the form, I am not getting any error.
Help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want client side `unobtrusive javascript validation`? or server side?

Comment: Server sides which I have defined into My Viewmodel

Answer (score 4):

Please go through the [**Here**](http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/02/validating-hidden-fields-in-asp-net-mvc-2/), it is very helpful

Client side validation for hidden fields is not working, because jQuery validation ignore all hidden tags.

You must define HiddenRequiredValidator class to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 4):

for validating only for particular hidden field, do this.

```
<script>
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        ignore: $('#CustomerID') 
    });
</script>
```

**OR for specific form**

```
$('#myform').validate({
        ignore: []
    });
```

Comment: This will ignore validation for the id `CustomerID` :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery validation plugin by default it will ignore `hidden` fields. To validate hidden fields change the default settings

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: [],
    // other default options
});
```